# webpack can convert js to es6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, webpack-4

I using webpack to bundle my node application.

I see the result in the bundle that webpack convert from `const` to `var`. This is mean that webpack convert my files to es5.

How can I tell webpack to convert to es6? (leave the const as it is and/or use import keyword for example)

**app.js**

```
import {test} from './some';

const x = 1;

console.log('test', test);
console.log('this should be const in the bundle, not var. ', x);
```

**And the bundle is:**

```
"use strict";
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony import */ var _some__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./some */ "./some.js");

var x = 1;
console.log('test', _some__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["test"]);
console.log('this should be const in the bundle, not var. ', x);

/***/ }),
```

**my webpack config:**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = () => [
  {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './app.js'),
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist')
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    target: 'node',
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.m?js$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the [@babel/preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env) without any options. That will transform the code to ES5 and the documentation says it's not really recommended to use it this way. The whole point of the "env" preset is that you give a target platform and it will automatically apply the transformations, which are needed for that platform. Passing "targets.node"-option value true or "current" will transform the code for the currently used node-version. Using the preset with this option has the additional advantage, that upgrading node.js will not require any changes in Babel configuration and less code will be transformed, if the new node.js supports more of the ES features used.

Support for ECMAScript modules in node.js is still experimental, but you can disable module transformation by passing false to "modules"-option.

```
options: {
    presets: [[
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
            targets: {
                node: "current"
            },
            modules: false
        }
    ]]
}
```

Comment: yeah, it good for the const keyword. what about `import`? seem that have no change.. webpack bundle with `__webpack_require__` function, not import.

Comment: Webpack is a module bundler. It will bundle all your .js-files into one by default. If you don't want them to be bundled, then you shouldn't be using webpack at all. The bundle you have provided is not complete. The __webpack_require__()-function is also included in the bundle.

Comment: @Pretseli shouldn’t use webpack at all? What about code splitting or tree shaking?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: I'm not against using Webpack in general, but code splitting and tree shaking bring very little benefit in node.js (server) environment. That doesn't mean that you should never use Webpack for bundling node.js code. There are some special use cases, but that's not the real point here. If you don't want to bundle (which seems to be what was wanted here), then using Webpack is like hitting a nail with a drill.

Comment: @Pretseli server environment?! I didn’t catch that. Personally it doesn’t make sense to compile for node.